# How to marshall pointer to array of char[256] from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, marshalling

I have C++ method which has following signature:

```
typedef char TNameFile[256];

void Foo(TNameFile** output);
```

I've run out of ideas how to marshall it.

Comment: Why have a pointer to a pointer to an array? Seems like at least one of those is unnecessary. Possibly both, in this case the array might as well be the return value.

Comment: @millimoose it is pointer to output array of TNameFile which is created inside Foo. This is thirdparty library. Can't do anything with signature and contents

Comment: Use `static extern void Foo(IntPtr output)` and then use `Marshal` class to walk the array and read the contents

Comment: What have you tried?  You need to send the pointer of the address that starts the array.  An array is already ( more or less ) an address.

Comment: I'd say both indirections are not necessary... (unless you want to allocate the memory in C# and assign to "output" in C++, which would result in a WORLD OF PAIN)

Comment: @Redwan Ah, it's an output *array of filenames*, not a single output firename. (You might edit the clarification into the question, the intent of three-star-programming isn't necessarily obvious.) Odd API design; is it an option to create a native "glue" library to translate to signatures dotnet will understand more readily?

Comment: @millimoose Well I am trying to get rid of such glue library. About API design: it was made by mathematicians not software developers, there are lots of such stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming they return an empty string as last element:

```
static extern void Foo(ref IntPtr output);

IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
Foo(ref ptr);
while (Marshal.ReadByte(ptr) != 0)
{
   Debug.Print(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr, 256).TrimEnd('\0'));
   ptr = new IntPtr(ptr.ToInt64() + 256);
}
```

**EDIT:** Since I've written the above code on my smartphone, I tested the code this morning and it seems like it should work (I just had to add the `TrimEnd('\0')`). Here is my test case:

```
class Program
{
    const int blockLength = 256;

    /// <summary>
    /// Method that simulates your C++ Foo() function
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="output"></param>
    static void Foo(ref IntPtr output)
    {
        const int numberOfStrings = 4;
        byte[] block = new byte[blockLength];
        IntPtr dest = output = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((numberOfStrings * blockLength) + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStrings; i++)
        {
            byte[] source = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test " + i);
            Array.Clear(block, 0, blockLength);
            source.CopyTo(block, 0);
            Marshal.Copy(block, 0, dest, blockLength);
            dest = new IntPtr(dest.ToInt64() + blockLength);
        }
        Marshal.WriteByte(dest, 0); // terminate
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method that calls the simulated C++ Foo() and yields each string
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static IEnumerable<string> FooCaller()
    {
        IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        Foo(ref ptr);
        while (Marshal.ReadByte(ptr) != 0)
        {
            yield return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr, blockLength).TrimEnd('\0');
            ptr = new IntPtr(ptr.ToInt64() + blockLength);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string fn in FooCaller())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fn);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

One question remains: **who is going to free the buffer?**

Answer (score -1):

It will make your life a lot easier if you use C++/CLI instead of native C++, you won't have to worry about unsafe code and marhsalling:

```
array<Byte>^ cppClass::cppFunction(TNameFile** input, int size)
{
    array<Byte>^ output = gcnew array<Byte>(size);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        output[i] = (**input)[i];

    return output;
}
```

If you must use marshalling then try using [Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx) as WouterH suggested in his answer.